# How to use clangd to find headers of gcc on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, clangd

My system is macOS 12.3 21E230 arm64 and I have installed `gcc` and `llvm` from homebrew.
I use `Neovim` as editor and use `nvim-lsp` via `clangd` to complete my code, and it works well with `clang`.
Now I want to use `clangd` to find headers of gcc and compelete them in my code. I have tried to find answer from https://clangd.llvm.org/, but I haven't find any way to solve this problem.

I tried setting `--query-driver`, `-include-dir`, `-isysroot`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using `--query-driver` seems to be the most promising approach.

If it's not working, please share more details in the form of [clangd logs](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#gathering-logs).

Some clangd issues reported my Mac users that might contain helpful discussion are:

- https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/487
- https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/1079